# Where can I find a documentation of Lightning server-side controller's response?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, controller, custom-controller

Having a lightning controller's code:

```
var action = cmp.get("myAction");
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    // Callback code's here
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

I call for a server-side controller's method and after receiving a response, I handle it. The `response` is an object which contains various methods (and fields?) but I can't find any information about them.

From a [Calling a Server-Side Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm) page I found out for example that by using a `getError()` method I can get an array (btw shouldn't it be 'getErrors'?) of errors returned from the server. I suppose there are much more things to be discovered but I just don't know where to look for them.

Is there any documentation of the `response` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is the response object param coming back into the callback function is nothing but a representation of the [Aura Action](http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference?topic=api:Action) object.

So you will have all of the properties and methods of the [Action object](http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference?topic=api:Action) (listed in the open source Aura docs) available in the response object.

Comment: This is correct.